# How can I install laravel framework for NetBeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, netbeans-7.4

I have installed Laravel and I want to use use framework annotations and code completion in the NetBeans 7.4 IDE, there is no Laravel plugin in the section "Install plug-ins". I have found a plug in for Netbeans on github but I am unsure how I install it, here is the link https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-laravel-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [repository's discussion](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-laravel-plugin/issues/8):

> Please download a nbm for your version of NetBeans.
>   https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-laravel-plugin/releases
>
> Then, please try to add the plugin : Tools > Plugins > Downloaded >
>   Add